# Terminal error File system read only (Solo lectura)

Tags: command-line, wine, filesystem

When I install a terminal application in the following error occurs
Cuando instalo una applicacion por terminal me ocurre el siguiente error

```
omega@omega-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
[sudo] password for omega: 
sudo: Can't open /var/lib/sudo/omega/0: Sistema de archivos de solo lectura
W: No se utilizan bloqueos para el archivo de bloqueo de sólo lectura /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: se interrumpió la ejecución de dpkg, debe ejecutar manualmente «sudo dpkg --configure -a» para corregir el problema 
omega@omega-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for omega: 
sudo: Can't open /var/lib/sudo/omega/0: Sistema de archivos de solo lectura
dpkg: error: no se puede acceder al área de estado de dpkg: Sistema de archivos de solo lectura
```

How do I fix this?
Como lo soluciono?

Comment: Did you by mistake change permissions of /var/lib/sudo/omega/0. Plz run "ls -al" in /var/lib/sudo/omega/0 and add the output to question

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that another application is locking the package manager.

Is Synaptic open?
Are you updating your system or some applications using Update Manager?
Are you installing an application using Software Center?

If so, wait until these operations are completed, and try to install your application again.